# No me crea una tarjeta con la info del link whatsapp con react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, seo

estoy intentando hacer que al compartir un link por rrss o whatapp, aparezca una tarjeta con la informacion del link para lo cual instale `Helmet` y cree una funcion a la cual se le pasan argumentos y estos a traves de `helmet` actualiza los metadata del head en el archivo `public/index.html` (adjunto image):

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
      <meta name="title" content="titulo" data-react-helmet="true" />
      <meta name="description" content="descripcion" data-react-helmet="true" />
```

Por otro lado, le he añadido para que haya efectivamente un cambio con `helmet` en los meta el atributo  `data-react-helmet`. Ahora la funcion que recibe los argumentos y que retorna los meta actualizados es la siguiente:

```
    // React
    import React from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

    // Helmet
    import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

    const HeaderMetaData = ({pageProps}) => {

        const title = pageProps.title ? pageProps.title : '';
        const description = pageProps.description ? pageProps.description : '';
        const image = require('../assets/images/imagen.png');
        
        return(
            <Helmet>
                <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
                <meta property="og:decription" content={description} />
                <meta property="og:image" content={image} />
                
                <meta property="twitter:title" content={title} />
                <meta property="twitter:decription" content={description} />
                <meta property="twitter:image" content={image} />
            </Helmet>
        )
    }

    HeaderMetaData.propTypes = {
        title: PropTypes.string,
        description: PropTypes.string
    }

    export default HeaderMetaData;
```

Y esta funcion se llama en distintas vistas y se le pasa un objeto y un string:

```
<HeaderMetaData pageProps={course}/>
```

Ahora bien, los cambios estan ya listos y en produccion, al revisar la url actualiza los meta tanto para el home como para la pagina en donde esta llamada la funcion pero cuando comparto a traves de whatsapp no se carga el link con la tarjeta como esperaba que lo hiciera. Sera que demora en pasar los cambios una vez subido a produccion?